# Objects are Flattening After Saving

Tags: modeling, sculpting, remesh, sculpt-mode

I've been sculpting a hand, and after I save it, it is flattened and rescaled when I open it again.  This just started in the last few days. I've been playing with it for about a month with no previous issues. Here's the before and re-opened models below.  Any ideas on why this happens or how to prevent?  Many thanks!  Bruce

[image: original model]

[image: reopened model]

Comment: I should add that it seems to be object based.  Other meshes not attached do not change after saving and re-opening (such as previous fingers not joined with the palm).

Comment: any animation defined on your scene?

Comment: Nope, nothing on the timeline.

Comment: Wait, you are correct!  Nothing on the timeline, but I did see that animation data associated with the object in the Outliner.  I cleared the data and it works now.  Two more questions:  1. Is there a way to clear all the animation data without going object by object in the outliner?  2. What in the animation data causes it?  Thanks for your help, it was driving me crazy.   Cheers, Bruce

Comment: Select objects and try typing 'remove animation' in the search menu. For the reason why an animation was defined, I don't know...